# How do I stop my divs from moving on other computers

Tags: html, css

On my website template I have divs that look fine on my screen. but if I restore down the browser or look at it on another computer the divs are moved.
Is there some sort of tag I can use to make my div stay in place.

//example of a div

```
#divtest{
    width:450px;
    height:75px;
    margin:20px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    display:flex;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: -7%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much everything in your CSS is specified in pixels, except the left margin which is based on a %.  The % here is the actual width of the window. Perhaps you might get the results you hope for by using a `px` value instead of a `%` value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create media queries for the different resolutions/devices that will use your website.

Another thing you could do is not depend on the 'px' unit but '%' or 'vh' for height and 'vw' for width.

Am I correct in what I suppose you're asking?